# Can I enter code directly from a source file?

Tags: documentation, minted

In a project I'm working, all the files are in the same folder (source codes, papers, images, etc).

In the documentation, I'm including some code with `minted` which is really great, but I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{minted}{c}
    \input{main.c}
\end{minted}
```

I know that won't work, but you can see what I want to do. The reason for this, is because I don't want to update documentation every time I change a source file, do you understand? The idea is to leave main.c as it is, and include that file automatically in the documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `\inputminted{c}{main.c}` or generally `\inputminted[options]{language}{filename}` -- see page 4 of the [minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) manual.

Comment: That happens to me bacause of the fast-manual reading :S

Answer (score 1):

I have used [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) in the past and am pleased with the results. It support several different programming languages, and is simple, yet powerful:

```
\lstset{language=C}
\input{funkyalg.c}
```

Comment: Listings is great, but IMO it isn't as powerful as minted. Because minted relays on pygmentize to make the sintax.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [`\usepackage{fancyvrb}`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/). It lets you do simple things like `\VerbatimInput{hello.c}` or fancy things like
`\fvset{frame=single,numbers=left,numbersep=3pt} 
\VerbatimInput{hello.c}` (see page 20 of the manual).